# Whether companies and consumers are in-group and out-group in misperception?

Tags: behavioral-economics

[Bursztyn (2021)](http://davidyyang.com/pdfs/misperception_draft.pdf) says that

> Misperceptions about others are widespread, asymmetric, much larger
> when about **out-group** members, and positively associated with one’s own
> attitudes.

Some examples of in-group and out-group in this paper are:

> Alesina, Miano and Stantcheva (2018) study perceptions of a native
> population about immigrants (out-group). A number of papers contrast
> beliefs about in-groups and out-groups. For example, Graham, Nosek and
> Haidt (2012) measure perceptions of Democrats and Republicans about
> their respective in-groups’ and out-groups’ political opinions.

I am wondering that in one opinion: "**companies want to collude to practice the price-fixing**", so in this case, the companies are in-group and consumers are out-group?

Comment: I am very sorry to ask this but your last sentence (I am wondering that in one opinion: "companies want to collude to practice the price-fixing", so in this case, the companies are in-group and consumers are out-group?) is a bit vague to me. Would you mind rephrasing or clarifying it? Perhaps it's just me, so you might not need to change anything.

Comment: @S.IasonKoutsoulis . I mean, "in-group" and "out-group" as in the quoted above, I try to put the assuming situation into the context of misperception. Thank you for your question, please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks a heap. In specific, in a misconception, we have the in-group and out-group.

Comment: I am afraid I do find the question unclear. But that might just be the late of the hour talking. I'll revisit the question tomorrow.

Comment: @lason: Thanks  a heap, see you tomorrow